# Java Spring Boot Redis has occurred nested exception is java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: event executor terminated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, redis

My service is built with spring boot REST API with Redis.
Some time face with error that logs:

```
nested exception is java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: event executor terminated
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Unknown redis exception; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: event executor terminated
at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.getFallback(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:53) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:43) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.convertLettuceAccessException(LettuceConnection.java:270) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceStringCommands.convertLettuceAccessException(LettuceStringCommands.java:799) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceStringCommands.setEx(LettuceStringCommands.java:232) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultedRedisConnection.setEx(DefaultedRedisConnection.java:302) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultStringRedisConnection.setEx(DefaultStringRedisConnection.java:1003) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultValueOperations$4.potentiallyUsePsetEx(DefaultValueOperations.java:268) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultValueOperations$4.doInRedis(DefaultValueOperations.java:261) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:228) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:188) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:96) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultValueOperations.set(DefaultValueOperations.java:256) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.3.RELEASE]
```

I have researched and fixed it with lettuce pool solution. My config in application.yaml
redis:

```
host: ${REDIS_HOST}
  port: ${REDIS_PORT}
  password: ${REDIS_PASSWORD}
  cachePrefix: ${spring.application.name}
  defaultExpiration: 300
  lettuce:
    pool:
      maxActive: ${REDIS_POOL_ACTIVE:40}
      maxIdle: ${REDIS_POOL_MAX_IDLE:40}
      minIdle: ${REDIS_POOL_MIN_IDLE:4}
```

My configuration Redis class

```
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class RedisConfiguration extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

    @Autowired
    private  RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory;

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public RedisExpireProperties expireProperties() {
        return new RedisExpireProperties();
    }


    @Bean
    public RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager(LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory,
                                               RedisExpireProperties expireProperties) {
        RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .disableCachingNullValues()
                .entryTtl(Duration.ofSeconds(expireProperties.getDefaultExpiration()))
                .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(RedisSerializer.json()));

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(expireProperties.getCachePrefix())) {
            String cachePrefix = "." + expireProperties.getCachePrefix() + ":";
            redisCacheConfiguration.prefixKeysWith(cachePrefix);
            redisCacheConfiguration.usePrefix();
        }

        return RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder.fromConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory)
                .cacheDefaults(redisCacheConfiguration).build();

    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        return redisTemplate;
    }
```

But This error still appears. Please suggest for me a new solution to resolve the error.
Many thanks!